# index.html showing up when I dont have one

Tags: html, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

Please see for yourself:

www.cookeh.org
Press 'Home' button
www.cookeh.org/index.html

I have an index.php file however. And I have just got rid of all extensions of .php using htaccess. I am using Amazon EC2 to host my website.

When I test locally, this does not happen. Any reason for this? My instance has no index.html.

However, when you go to www.cookeh.org -> click 'Log In' button -> click 'Home' button, it will go to /index instead and not .html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear cache of your browser and visit your website again. If It does not fixes let me know via comments.

Edit. Here is your problem.

> http://www.cookeh.org/index.php

Comment: Thank you, that was a small error on my part. I sometimes forget about those things. I will accept your answer soon since this post is new :)